# Convert hours,minutes to days,hours,minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Query that shows downtime in hours, minutes but would need it to show it in Days,hours,minutes and maybe Another version that shows Days,hours

I'm not good at coding, sorry.

```
${SQL: SELECT CAST( CAST(('${N=Alerting;M=Downtime}') AS int) / 60 AS varchar) + ' hours '  + right('0' + CAST(CAST(('${N=Alerting;M=Downtime}') AS int) % 60 AS varchar(2)),2) + ' minutes'}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO, could you post an example of the final format you'd wish?

Comment: Are you certain that's SQL Server?

Comment: Hi, I need it to say  (days) Days, (hours) Hours,  (minutes) Minutes
and Another that says (days) Days, (hours) Hours
if that makes sense.

Comment: Pretty sure its SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
${SQL: SELECT CAST( CAST(('${N=Alerting;M=Downtime}') AS int) / 1440 AS varchar) + ' days '  + right('0' + CAST(CAST(('${N=Alerting;M=Downtime}') AS int) % 1440 / 60 AS varchar(2)),2) +  ' hours '  + right('0' + CAST(CAST(('${N=Alerting;M=Downtime}') AS int) % 60 AS varchar(2)),2) + ' minutes'}
```

Comment: One thing I noticed is that it says for an example: 20 Days 125 hours 05 minutes. How do I make so that if it reaches 24 hours it converts to a day instead? Do I just change 1440 to 24 for hours?